# Recursive grep with good efficiency

Tags: java

This question is very specific to me, so I cannot find related questions on Stack Overflow. So, I'm coding a grep shown below. I am confused on the `stringindextoutofboundexception`. The reason for that is because I am checking whether it is equals to `\0`. That means I am handling the out of bound exception, no?

Example:

```
grep("hello","llo");
```

This will return 3. That is because its start matching at `original[2]` which is position 3. However, I am encountering an out of index error. I've spent hours and I can't figure it out.

```
public static int grep(String ori, String ma){
    int toReturn = 0;
    int oCounter = 0;
    int i = 0;
    while (i < ma.length()){
      if (ori.charAt(toReturn) == ma.charAt(i)){
        i++;
        if (ma.charAt(i) == '\0'){ // error on this line
          return toReturn;
        }
        toReturn++;
        if (ori.charAt(toReturn) == '\0'){ // and this line if i delete the section above.
          return -1;
        }

      } else {
        i = 0;
        toReturn++;
      }

    }
    return -1;
}
```

Comment: It's been a while since I've done java, but I'm pretty sure that you don't explicitly check for `'\0'` like you might in c.

Comment: Are you trying to code a Recursive Algorithm for the Grep you have described? ( I would call it substring()..I think grep would find all instances of the "ma" and return a list perhaps a list of indexes into ori)

Answer (score 1):

You're getting an StringIndexOutOfBoundsException because you increment `i` inside the loop at a too early and wrong stage.

Checking for \0 is a C++ thing. Strings in java are not \0 terminated.

What you're writing is already done in the String class. There are several methods available.

```
System.out.println("hello".indexOf("llo"));
```

will print 2 because it's been found and starts at index 2. Feel free to add 1 if you dislike the starting at 0 for some reason.

You also ask "that means I'm handling the exception, no?". No, it doesn't. Exceptions are handled with a special syntax called try-catch statements. And example:

```
try {
    // possibly more lines of code here
    do_something_that_might_cause_exception();
    // possibly more lines of code here
} catch (Exception e) {
    // something did indeed cause an exception, and the variable e holds information about. We can do "exceptional" handling here, but for now we print some information.
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```